# Blasting Wilder with Chaotic Surge

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, archetype

I started playing a [Blasting](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/wilder/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/blasting-wilder/) Wilder with the added nutso idea of using the [chaotic wild surge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/wilder/#Chaotic_Surge) from the base class. I realize there is a huge risk/reward that comes with that combination. Onto my specific question.

Blasting Wilder does not gain a bonus to manifester level during a wild surge, instead adding an additional damage die for each point of wild surge bonus to the surge blast.

> A blasting wilder uses her wild surge not to improve her psionic powers, but to enhance her surge blast ability. Any time the blasting wilder invokes a wild surge, she gains no increase to her manifester level, but adds one die of damage to her surge blast for each point of the wild surge and can expend her psionic focus to use her surge blast as a free action in the same round she used her wild surge, although she may only do this once per round, even if wild surging more than once per round. This ability functions in all other ways as Wild Surge, including the risk of psychic enervation, and is modified by the wilder’s surge choice as normal. Wild surges that do not increase the manifester level, such as Efficient Surge, cannot be used with this archetype.

The chaotic surge requires a d4 roll to determine what bonus (or penalty) you would receive to your manifester level. A roll of 1 takes whatever the standard wild surge bonus is and turns it into a penalty. A roll of 2 or 3 applies the bonus as normal, while a roll of 4 doubles the bonus.

> The chaotic wilder unlocks ways to increase her manifester level beyond the dreams of most wilders, but doing so is even more dangerous. When the chaotic wilder invokes a wild surge, she rolls a d4. If the result is a 1, the chaotic wilder’s power manifests at one manifester level lower than normal. If this would result in a manifester level too low to manifest the power, the wilder is shaken until the start of her next turn and the power fails, although the chaotic wilder does not spend any power points. If the result is a 2 or 3, the chaotic wilder’s manifester level is improved by 1. If the result is a 4, the chaotic wilder’s manifester level is improved by 2. When the chaotic wilder’s wild surge improves (3rd, 7th, 11th, 15th, and 19th levels) or when using perfect surge, treat each bonus the same way. For example, at 7th level, a result of 1 would mean the manifester level is reduced by 3, a result of 2-3 would mean the manifester level is increased by 3, while a result of 4 would mean the manifester level is increased by 6. [...]

During my last game I succeeded on avoiding psychic enervation, but my roll for the chaotic surge was a 1. My question is how that would interact with the Blasting Wilder archetype? By my math, it cancels out the damage of the surge blast. Wild Surge bonus of +2, Standard surge blast of 2d6, +2 applied as a penalty (in this case a penalty of 2d6), equals 0. So, the action is lost/wasted/fizzled? Is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I added some links and quotes to help people looking into this. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a RAW answer for this combination...however, extrapolating from the [Blasting Wilder](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/wilder/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/blasting-wilder/)'s interaction with a normal [Wild Surge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/wilder/#Wild_Surge_Su), I would personally rule that rolling a 1 on the d4 for a [Chaotic Surge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/wilder/#Chaotic_Surge), then you should reduce the damage dice rolled for your Surge Blast by the value of Wild Surge, which would generally result in no damage being done (not sure if there are any other circumstances or modifiers that would increase your Surge Blast dice).